# How to set a image using querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

In my javascript code i'm using querySelector to set some data to several span tags i have. For example i have an innerHTML like the following.

```
this.innerHTML = `

            <div id="templates" class="template_style">

              <template id="book-template">
              <div class="card_component">
              <!--<img class="user_image" src="user_image"/>-->
                <span class="firstName"></span><span class="lastName"></span><span class="category"></span>
                </div>
              </template>

              <template id="book-template2">
              <div class="card_component">
                <span class="balance"></span><span class="bank"></span><span class="description"></span>
                </div>
              </template>

             <div id="books"></div>
           </div>
       `;
```

And i am setting data to `<span class="firstName">` like `instance.querySelector('.firstName').innerHTML = book.firstName;`

How can i do the same for a image tag?

```
<img class="user_image"/>
instance.querySelector('.user_image').innerHTML = book.picture;
```

this does not work. How can set my image to src of the image tag using querySelector?

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `src` attribute as follows:

```
instance.querySelector('.user_image').src = book.picture;
```